# Revoke and Grant not working as expected

Tags: python, pubnub

I'm trying to a user read/write access on channel 'test' for a specified amount of time and then remove those permissions after the time has elapsed.

I have tried to revoke using grant and by letting the token expire naturally through its ttl but none are working as I would expect.

On my server I have: (keys removed)

```
pnconfig = PNConfiguration()                
pnconfig.publish_key = 'pubkey'
pnconfig.subscribe_key = 'subkey'
pnconfig.secret_key = 'skey'
pubnub = PubNub(pnconfig)

pubnub.subscribe().channels('test').with_presence().execute()

pubnub.grant().read(False).write(False).manage(False).ttl(0).sync()
# have also tried
#pubnub.grant().read(False).write(False).manage(False).channels('test').ttl(0).sync()
```

I later grant an arbitrary user permissions using a randomly generated key 'userkey'. Even though I use a ttl of 2 it lives much longer than 2 minutes.

```
# ttl(1) should last for 1 minute but instead is instantly expired 
# so I am using ttl(2) instead. I would prefer the user have permissions
# revoked after 1 minute
pubnub.grant().read(True).write(True).manage(False).channels('test').auth_keys(userkey).ttl(2).sync()
```

Because of the issue with ttl I have tried calling grant again after the time it should expire but to no avail. The user is still able to read/write even after this is done:

```
pubnub.grant().read(False).write(False).manage(False).channels('test').auth_keys(userkey).ttl(0).sync()
```

---

After this, the client connects using the generated userkey as their auth key. This is done on in javascript as follows:

```
 pubnub = PUBNUB.init({
    publish_key     : 'pubkey',
    subscribe_key   : 'subkey',
    auth_key        : userkey,
    leave_on_unload : true
 });
```

Comment: Just a quick check, if you have included the **`SECRET_KEY`** in your PubNub SDK v4, then Full Access is automatically open.